# Impossible to install ia libs 32 on 64 bits ubuntu

Tags: package-management, software-installation, wine, 64-bit, dependencies

I installed ubuntu some days ago (15.04 64bits), I'm new on it.

I installed bumblebee and now that I try to install Wine, Steam or Skype I always get this error.

I've tried some solutions posted on forums ..etc. but still the same.  "You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libGL.so.1" I can't install these libraries.

I'm not familiar on ubuntu yet so I don't know what I need to mention in this post, I'll post everything necessary when you ask me.

Here is the error message.

```
The following packages contain dependencies unsatisfied :
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Depends: libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 (>= 2.4.63) but will not be installed
                    Depends: libdrm-intel1:i386 (>= 2.4.48) but will not be installed
                    Depends: libdrm-nouveau2:i386 (>= 2.4.38) but will not be installed
                    Depends: libdrm-radeon1:i386 (>= 2.4.31) but will not be installed
                    Depends: libdrm2:i386 (>= 2.4.38) but will not be installed
libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libdrm2:i386 (>= 2.3.1) but will not be installed
```

Thanks a lot :)

## EDIT : output : apt-cache policy libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386

```
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386:
  Installed : (none)
  Candidate : 11.0.2+git20151008+11.0.b1230e3e-0ubuntu0ricotz~vivid
 Version table :
 11.0.2+git20151008+11.0.b1230e3e-0ubuntu0ricotz~vivid 0
    500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu/ vivid/main i386 Packages
 10.5.9-2ubuntu1~vivid2 0
    500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main i386 Packages
 10.5.2-0ubuntu1 0
    500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main i386 Packages
 9.1.1-0ubuntu3 0
    500 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main i386 Packages
libdrm-amdgpu1:i386:
  Installed : (none)
 Candidate : 2.4.65+git20151008.8c4a1cbd-0ubuntu0ricotz~vivid
Version Table :
 2.4.65+git20151008.8c4a1cbd-0ubuntu0ricotz~vivid 0
    500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu/ vivid/main i386 Packages
libdrm-intel1:i386:
Installed : (none)
Candidate : 2.4.65+git20151008.8c4a1cbd-0ubuntu0ricotz~vivid
Version :
 2.4.65+git20151008.8c4a1cbd-0ubuntu0ricotz~vivid 0
    500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu/ vivid/main i386 Packages
 2.4.60-2 0
    500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main i386 Packages
 2.4.43-0ubuntu1 0
    500 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main i386 Packages
libdrm-nouveau2:i386:
Installed : (none)
Candidate : 2.4.65+git20151008.8c4a1cbd-0ubuntu0ricotz~vivid
Version table :
 2.4.65+git20151008.8c4a1cbd-0ubuntu0ricotz~vivid 0
    500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu/ vivid/main i386 Packages
 2.4.60-2 0
    500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main i386 Packages
 2.4.43-0ubuntu1 0
    500 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main i386 Packages
libdrm-radeon1:i386:
Installed : (none)
Candidate : 2.4.65+git20151008.8c4a1cbd-0ubuntu0ricotz~vivid
Version table :
 2.4.65+git20151008.8c4a1cbd-0ubuntu0ricotz~vivid 0
    500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu/ vivid/main i386 Packages
 2.4.60-2 0
    500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main i386 Packages
 2.4.43-0ubuntu1 0
    500 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main i386 Packages
libdrm2:i386:
 Installed : (none)
 Candidate : 2.4.65+git20151008.8c4a1cbd-0ubuntu0ricotz~vivid
Version table :
 2.4.65+git20151008.8c4a1cbd-0ubuntu0ricotz~vivid 0
    500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu/ vivid/main i386 Packages
 2.4.60-2 0
    500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main i386 Packages
 2.4.43-0ubuntu1 0
    500 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main i386 Packages
libgl1-mesa-glx:i386:
Installed : (none)
Candidate : 11.0.2+git20151008+11.0.b1230e3e-0ubuntu0ricotz~vivid
Version table :
 11.0.2+git20151008+11.0.b1230e3e-0ubuntu0ricotz~vivid 0
    500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu/ vivid/main i386 Packages
 10.5.9-2ubuntu1~vivid2 0
    500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main i386 Packages
 10.5.2-0ubuntu1 0
    500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main i386 Packages
 9.1.1-0ubuntu3 0
    500 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main i386 Packages
```

## EDIT : apt-cache policy libgl1-mesa-dri:i386

```
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386:
 Installé : (aucun)
 Candidat : 10.5.9-2ubuntu1~vivid2
 Table de version :
 10.5.9-2ubuntu1~vivid2 0
    500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main i386 Packages
 10.5.2-0ubuntu1 0
    500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main i386 Packages
 9.1.1-0ubuntu3 0
    500 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main i386 Packages
```

## EDIT : "sudo apt-cache policy libgl1-mesa-dri:i386"

```
*libdrm-intel1:
Installé : 2.4.65+git20150922.f3c6740f-0ubuntu0ricotz~vivid
Candidat : 2.4.65+git20150922.f3c6740f-0ubuntu0ricotz~vivid
Table de version :
*** 2.4.65+git20150922.f3c6740f-0ubuntu0ricotz~vivid 0
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 2.4.60-2 0
    500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
```

## EDIT : sudo ppa-purge ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa

```
Updating packages lists
PPA to be removed: xorg-edgers ppa
Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: xorg-edgers ppa
```

## EDIT : sudo apt-cache policy libgl1-mesa-dri:i386

```
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386:
Installed : (none)
Candidate : 10.5.9-2ubuntu1~vivid2
Table de version :
 10.5.9-2ubuntu1~vivid2 0
    500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main i386 Packages
 10.5.2-0ubuntu1 0
    500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main i386 Packages
 9.1.1-0ubuntu3 0
    500 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main i386 Packages
  N: « xorg-edgers-ubuntu-ppa-vivid.list.disable » in the repertory « /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ » was ignored because he uses an invalid extension
  N: « xorg-edgers-ubuntu-ppa-vivid.list.disable » in the repertory « /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ » was ignored because he uses an invalid extension
```

Comment: Please, don't change the question without that I say that. Sorry **;)** That's too confusing. And don't delete the output of previous commands, also confusing for readers. And add changes at the end of your question.

Comment: Please remove your comments below your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks very funny.

1. Remove the `old-releases` repositories

   ```
   sudo sed -i '/old-releases/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
2. You had the PPA `ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa` in your system, but deleted the file in `/etc/apt/sources.listd`. Therefore re-add and purge in a clean way

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/pp
   sudo ppa-purge ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
   ```

   and a little bit housekeeping

   ```
   sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xorg-edgers-ubuntu-ppa-vivid.list.disable
   ```
3. Repair your system

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -f
   ```